# Typeorm Entity Insert Without Synchronization

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM and NestJs to work with an existing MySql database.  There is a shared table that I must insert records into, which has an auto-incrementing primary key.  Since the table is shared, I have synchronize turned off.

When I setup my TypeORM entity with the @PrimaryGeneratedColumn decorator, I get an error stating that the column "doesn't have a default value".  If I change the decorator to @Column, then I receive an error regarding no primary key.

Can anyone tell me how I should setup my TypeORM entity so that I may insert a record into a table with a auto-incrementing column, where synchronize is turned off?

**UPDATE**

Here's a excerpt of the MySql table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tIntegrationItem (
    IntegrationItemID       mediumint AUTO_INCREMENT    NOT NULL,
    Description             varchar(200)                NOT NULL,
    CreatedDateTime         dateTime                    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (IntegrationItemID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Here's an excerpt of the entity:

```
@Entity({ name: "tIntegrationItem" })
export class IntegrationItem {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    integrationItemId : number;

    @Column()
    description : string;

    @Column()
    createdDateTime  : Date = new Date();
}
```

Here's the error that I receive:

> [Nest] 26248   - 01/22/2020, 2:18:43 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'IntegrationItemID' doesn't have a default value +18075ms
>   QueryFailedError: ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'IntegrationItemID' doesn't have a default value

Comment: For a more detailed examination, please add a schema description of your existing table, the entity class and an error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the database configuration to a different database, and the application worked fine.  I had the application configured to work with a local instance of MySql, which was not setup properly.  I don't know the exact reason, though.

**UPDATE**

I've since learned that my local database did not match the server instance. When it was setup, the primary key column was not setup to auto-increment. *smh*

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be column name related.

`integrationItemId : number;`

`IntegrationItemID`